# show/hide section in wordpress with select values

Tags: javascript, select, show-hide

I use Divi Theme in Wordpress.
I have sections that I gave IDs.
I have a select, and for each option value I use the sections IDs.
I want show one section by changing the select option and hide the other section that is showed.

Here is the select :

```
<select name="years" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="">TOUTES LES ANNÉES </option>
      <option value="section2020">2020</option>
      <option value="section2019">2019</option>
      <option value="section2018">2018</option>
      <option value="section2017">2017</option>
      <option value="section2016">2016</option>
      <option value="section2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

Here is the javascript :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  if (x.style === "display:none;") {
    x.style = "display:block";
  } else {
    x.style = "display:none;";
  }
}
</script>
```

Could you tell my why it's not working ?

thanks
Caroline

Comment: HI I added one answer, have a look, I explained why your code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to style a string value `x.style`

If we see closely `var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;` this is returning a string value not an html element. But yes we can use this string value to get html element and make it visible and hide other.

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
    var selectedValue = selectElement.value;
    var selectedElement = document.getElementById(selectedValue);
          
    if (selectedElement.style.display === "none") {
       var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
       for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
       elements[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       selectedElement.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
            selectedElement.style.display = "none";
         }
}
```

```html
        <select name="years" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
              <option value="">TOUTES LES ANNÉES </option>
              <option value="section2020">2020</option>
              <option value="section2019">2019</option>
              <option value="section2018">2018</option>
              <option value="section2017">2017</option>
              <option value="section2016">2016</option>
              <option value="section2015">2015</option>
        </select>


    <div id="section2020" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2020</h1></div>
    <div id="section2019" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2019</h1></div>
    <div id="section2018" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2018</h1></div>
    <div id="section2017" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2017</h1></div>
    <div id="section2016" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2016</h1></div>
    <div id="section2015" class='section' style='display:none'><h1>2015</h1></div>
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't works, it make disappear options into the select

Comment: Okay so you want to hide the whole select element? okay let me update

Comment: no, sorry for the misunderstood, I want to hide and show sections, that are distant divs. English is not my language, sorry if I explain not so good

Comment: If you add your `section<ID>` `DOM` structure then this problem will be easy to resolve.

Comment: BTW I Updated the answer have a look. Now this can show the section, but I know what is the `section<ID>` dom looks like then will be easy to implement hide show feature

Comment: thanks for you answer, could you help me to hide other div when one is shown?

Comment: Done have a look

Comment: That works in your demo, but into my wordpress with Divi theme, that doesn't works. I will continue to search, thank you for your help anyway!!

Comment: Yes ofcourse works in my demo because I wrote this demo according to my section dom elements. I asked you to post of show your sections dom structure but you didn't post anything!

Answer (score 0):

So thank you so much @Dupinder Singh. After playing with the code, I got it to work on my DIVI theme.

However, since you can't put in-line CSS styles on a Section in DIVI, I did the following. I went under each section and under the Advanced Tab -> Custom CSS -> Main Content = display: none;

Then since each section appeared like so  I changed the javascript to the following:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
        var selectElement = document.getElementById("serviceoptions"); 
        var selectedValue = selectElement.value;
        var selectedElement = document.getElementById(selectedValue);
              
        if (selectedElement.style.display === "") {
           var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
           for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
              elements[i].style.display = "";
           }
           selectedElement.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
                selectedElement.style.display = "none";
             }
    }
    </script>
```

The following was my HTML for the Selection Menu:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<Select id="serviceoptions" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="">Choose a Service</option>
<option value="behavior">Behavior Resources</option>
<option value="case">Case Management Resources</option>
<option value="education">Education Resources</option>
<option value="speceducation">Specialized Education Resources</option>
<option value="afterschool">After School Programs</option>
<option value="kidhealth">Children's Health Resources</option>
<option value="kidoralhealth">Children's Oral Health Resources</option>
<option value="homevisit">Home Visiting Resources</option>
<option value="nutrition">Nutrition Resources</option>
<option value="parent">Parent Resources</option>
<option value="transpo">Transportation Resources</option>
<option value="kidcare">Child Care Resources</option>
</select>
</p>
```

You can see it in action here: [first1thousand.com/resources](https://www.first1thousand.com/resources)